# regex pattern a then b then a, one or more times

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use regex to find a repeating pattern but I can't work out how to do it. I want to get all matches where there is a number then a plus symbol then another number, including repeats.

So for example, if the string is "5+2-6+10+3", I want to end up with ["5+2", "6+10+3"]

So far I've got

```
\d*\+\d*
```

But that doesn't capture the final "+3" in the example above. I had a few attempts using brackets for capturing groups but I couldn't get the output I wanted.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can use a repeating group like `\d+(?:\+\d+)+`, and note that `\d*\+\d*` can also match a mere `+`

Comment: If `2-6+10+3` or `2-1` is valid then you would want `\d+(?:\+\d+)*`

Comment: Awesome, thanks both. If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept. Thanks for pointing out my mistake using * instead of + too

Comment: You should clarify which comment solved your problem. My regex is functionally different from TheFourthBird's

Comment: Oh sorry yeah, I hadn't realised how they were different. The first comment solved my problem as 2-6+10+3 is not valid for me

Comment: @Thefourthbird Just pinging you in case you've moved on from this question.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I left it as a comment, you can post it if you want :-)

Answer (score 1):

Solved using the following (thanks The fourth bird):

```
\d+(?:\+\d+)+
```